# Excel function to match a substring from text with a list

Tags: excel, string-matching

I'm trying to extract the substring from an entire string and rename it using v-lookup. I don't want to use the text to column function.

The textstring in column A:

Adf_ROCLeader_BAN_728x90_CPM_STD _**BRD** _NRT_DCK
MMC_ContextualLarRec_BAN_336x280_CPM_STD _**LDS** _RTG_DCK
Adf_ROC_DLBD_728x90_CPM_STD_**DRS**_NRT_NOR_DCK

Vlookup list

BRD - Branding

DRS - Direct Response

LDS - Leads

So basically, the function would need to see if the cells in column A contain BRD, DRS, or LDS (list) and than rename it to the names corresponding with the list.

I tried using 3 formula's nested in one: Search, Mid, and Vlookup, but the Search function doesn't seem to work on a list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With your lookup values (i.e. BRD, DRS, LDS) and corresponding replacements (i.e. Branding, Direct Response, Leads) in D1:D3 and E1:E3 respectively, and the first string on which you wish to perform the replacement in A1, enter this formula in B1:

=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($D$1:$D$3,A1),$D$1:$D$3),LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($D$1:$D$3,A1),$E$1:$E$3)),A1)

Note that, if none of the search strings is found, the cell entry is returned unchanged. Also note that, since you gave no cases in which **more than one** of the search strings is present in a given entry, this is assumed to not be possible, and no accounting has been made for it in the above solution.

Regards